# Mongodb regex query

Tags: regex, mongodb

Inside Mongodb I would like to search with regex. For example I would like to make a query to returns all of these:

```
"ab-cd/ef" 
"ab/cd.ef" 
"abcdef"
```

I have created that query

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({detail:{$regex:"ab.*.cd.*.ef"}}
```

but the problem is that it cannot find `"abcdef"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing `.`s so that it's just:

```js
db.getCollection('collection').find({detail: {$regex: "ab.*cd.*ef"}}
```

With the trailing `.`s it's requiring at least one char between each group.